# EasyAdmin list action for current user

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I'm trying to retrieve a list of objects from database where `Entity.user = "current user"`.

It's a ManyToOne relation between an Entity entity and a User Entity

I tried to use the dql-filter option in the bundle config but couldn't find a parameter variable like we can find in Controller `$this->getUser()` or in Twig `{{app.user}}`

I tried to use custom controller but I am confused as the documentation is not very detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a custom controller and overwrite [findAll](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/src/Controller/AdminControllerTrait.php#L523) or [createListQueryBuilder](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/src/Controller/AdminControllerTrait.php#L550) by always adding a DQL-filter. Something a bit like this:

```
protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
{
    if (null === $dqlFilter) {
        $dqlFilter = sprintf('entity.user = %s', $this->getUser()->getId());
    } else {
        $dqlFilter .= sprintf(' AND entity.user = %s', $this->getUser()->getId());
    }

    return parent::createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter);
}
```

Comment: You might have to fiddle with the property name, but you should get the idea. :)

Comment: If i overwrite the method it won't change globaly for other entities?

Comment: No, if you create a custom Controller for an Entity and then assign it to the entity in the configuration (by adding a key controller to the easy_admin.yaml under `entities.<Entity>.controller: <CustomController>`) only this entity will use the controller

Comment: Error in Twig: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Semantical Error] line 0, col 48 near 'user = 1 ORDER': Error: 'user' is not defined.").

Comment: I changed user to entity.user and it works!
Update the anwser and i will put it as anwsered.

Comment: i have a question it's been one week i'm struggling with newaction i don't know how to get current user id for a field i tried like this
```
   - { property: 'idUser', type: 'entity', type_options: { class: 'App\Entity\User', 
      multiple: false }}
```

 but in this case i should chose the user. but what exactly i want is to when ever i create an article it should get the current user id and save in my database